# Too many 'steps' when executing a pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a large data set which needs to be partition into 1,000 separate files, and the simplest implementation we wanted to use is to apply PartitionFn which, given an element of the data set, returns a random integer between 1 and 1,000.
The problem with this approach is it ends up creating 1,000 PCollections and the pipeline does not launch as there seems to be a hard limit on the number of 'steps' (which correspond to the boxes shown on the job monitoring UI in execution graph).

Is there a way to increase this limit (and what is the limit)?

The solution we are using to get around this issue is to partition the data into a smaller subsets first (say 50 subsets), and for each subset we run another layer of partitioning pipelines to produce 20 subsets of each subset (so the end result is 1000 subsets), but it'll be nice if we can avoid this extra layer (as ends up creating 1 + 50 pipelines, and incurs the extra cost of writing and reading the intermediate data).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `Partition` transform and introducing many steps in the pipeline consider using either of the following approaches:

1. Many sinks support the option to specify the number of output shards. For example, `TextIO` has a [withNumShards](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html#withNumShards-int-) method. If you pass this 1000 it will produce 1000 separate shards in the specified directory.
2. Using the shard number as a key and using a `GroupByKey` + a `DoFn` to write the results.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but the suggested approaches did not work for us for several reasons.
Approach 1 with the number of shards: This does not guarantee uniformity (or any other property we wish to enforce when partitioning) across the created 1000 files. Another caveat with this approach we found was that as a small number of workers finish up the last few files, the entire instance group is using up the resource, costing us a lot (we have a really large data set read from/written to GCS).

Comment: Approach 2: Due to the size of the data set and the size of each entry, GroupByKey will run out of memory (or if we push to the limit by using the max number of workers and highest memory machines, then it will be too costly for us, compared to the solution we are currently using).

Is there any possibility of supporting a larger number of steps than right now?

Comment: Can you clarify what out-of-memory issues you mean with GroupByKey? It's intended to support an unlimited number of keys and values-per-key (all values even for a single key do not need to fit in memory).

Comment: That's interesting -- we initially thought that the memory should not be an issue even if a hot key is associated with many values, but what we experienced was a bit different. Our pipelines "hang" for a very long time, and eventually "fail" at the [co]grouByKey step, but it would run fine if we increase memory (e.g. n1-highmem-4). So we thought it was the memory issue (we also tested with larger PD size, 1TB/worker, which did not help). Our pipeline does not utilize Combine yet (which may resolve our problem). I can't share the details right now, but will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: [part 1 of 2] Since the comments have character limits, maybe I can give refer you to the job IDs for which GroupByKey caused trouble (but these jobs have nothing to do with the original question about partitioning large data into 1000 subsets, as this is a different pipeline). 
2016-12-05_20_15_20-447898864565187414 This job was bound to fail (we've seen it multiple time), so I cancelled it to avoid paying for nothing. 
With more workers and higher memory, the same job (and same data) ran successfully: 2016-12-06_15_18_57-16709842549314120266

Comment: [part 2 of 2] The next day (= today), the same job failed: 2016-12-06_20_15_35-5396824174840893324 (but on a different input).
Again, if we increase the number of nodes/memory, it works just fine (2016-12-06_21_50_12-11310646626168049650). We have witnessed multiple jobs with the same issue (they fail during group by key step), and our conclusion was that workers needed more memory due to some hot keys with values (and hot keys tend to have larger size data per value). Is there something we are missing here?

Comment: Is the step they are failing a GroupByKey step or a CoGroupByKey step?

Comment: For the ones I mentioned, both are CoGroupByKey steps (sorry I thought those were GroupByKey steps for some reason).

Comment: I'd like to debug the issues you're having with "Approach 1". AFAIK withNumShards should make the shards more or less uniform; and there usually should not be any stragglers (I work on straggler elimination and would like to debug that); and even if there are stragglers for unavoidable reasons, in most cases we should be able to down-size the instance group if autoscaling is enabled. Do you have a job ID for that approach that I can look at?

Comment: The main issue with Approach 1 we found was: we want to split the data as uniformly as possible (not just in size, but to remove bias in data sets) as the subsets will be used for machine learning. The ML team found that the resulting subsets contained biasses -- and I suspect it is partly because any contiguous chunk in the input data has bias/correlation. So we wish to 'shuffle' the data (rows in input files) as uniformly as possible. For Approach 2, my colleague had a test run which was too costly (the VM cost) compared to the hypothetical VM cost of creating 1000 PCollections.